# Resize image on the fly and keep aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, .net, image, image-processing

I need to resize an image to display on different pages in different sizes, keeping the aspect ratio of the original image.

Can I do it programatically or do I need to preload images of different sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set just the width or just the height of an image and leave the other dimension unspecified, the browser will scale the image proportionally while maintaining its aspect ratio.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NRLQ5/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Css3 they you can use transform:scale(scalefactor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) class from System.Web.Helpers assembly.
It provides a method Resize, which allows you to resize keeping aspect ratio unchanged

```
public WebImage Resize(
    int width,
    int height,
    bool preserveAspectRatio,
    bool preventEnlarge
)
```

Beside that you can create WebImage instance using file path, stream, or byte array and easily add watermark.

```
WebImage image = new WebImage(Server.MapPath("~/upload/my_image.png"));
WebImage image_small_1 = image.Resize( Convert.ToInt32(image.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32(image.Height / 2), true, true );
```

You can save image to disk or if you environment allows it store in cache

```
image_small_1.Save(Server.MapPath("~/upload/my_image_small_1.png"), "png", true);

byte[] to_be_cached = image_small_1.GetBytes("png");
```