# How can I resize external images and serve them on-the-fly?

Tags: ruby, image, sinatra

I have a sinatra app that gets image urls from an API and I want to scale them and then serve them without storing them on the server. Most of the gems I have seen only get local images and then processes each one in a queue. I only need to scale five images and display them on the page. Is there a fast way to do this?

More Clarification:

I need a way to get an image externally (e.g. notmysite.com/img.jpg) and for the code to serve the scaled image on the page. I cant do it with css or other front-end methods because this page is going to be rendered by a script that distorts images scaled front-end.

Comment: More information would be a big help in answering this.

Comment: @iain I need a way to get an image externally (e.g. http://notmysite.com/img.jpg) and for the code to serve the scaled image on the page. I cant do it with css because this page is going to be rendered by a script that distorts images scaled with css

Comment: Do you have an example of one of the gems that does this for local files?

Comment: @iain something like [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @iain I used php to make an image resizing script. It was the easy way out.

Comment: glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Dragonfly uses imagemagick to scale the images. Here's some code I've cobbled together from previous stuff I've done with [MiniMagick](http://rubygems.org/gems/mini_magick), so it'll be fairly similar.

Get yourself the file into a [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html). I've done this here with [Faraday](http://rubygems.org/gems/faraday) and [Typheous](http://rubygems.org/gems/typhoeus). Then scale it using magick!

```
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday_middleware'
#require 'faraday/adapter/typhoeus' # see https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/226#issuecomment-9919517 if you get a problem with the requiring
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'

configure do
  Faraday.default_connection = Faraday::Connection.new( 
    :headers => { :accept =>  'image/*',
    :user_agent => "Sinatra via Faraday"}
  ) do |conn|
    conn.use Faraday::Adapter::Typhoeus
  end
end

helpers do
  def grab_image_and_scale
    response = Faraday.get url # you'll need to supply this variable somehow, your choice
    filename = "SOMETHING.jpg"
    tempfile = Tempfile.open(filename, 'wb') { |fp| fp.write(response.body) }

    thumb = MiniMagick::Image.open( tempfile.path )
    thumb.thumbnail( "75x75" )
    thumb.write( File.join settings.public, "images", "thumb_#{filename}") 

    scaled = MiniMagick::Image.open( secure_path )
    scaled.resize( "600" )
    scaled.write( File.join settings.public, "images", "scaled_#{filename}")
  end
end
```

I'll leave it to you to work out how to change the path to the public images folder into a tempfile (and it'd be nice if you shared how it's done:)

Answer (score 0):

One way, that is not related to Ruby or sinatra, is to add `width` and `height` attributes to `img` HTML tag. You'll end up with something like this:

```
<img src="img.source.from.API.JPG" width="2000px" height="100px" />
```

#### Edit

Another method is to change the dimension using javascript, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11333825/693597. You might consider writing your JS file and included in the header of your HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because the page is being rendered by a script that breaks images when they are resized like that. It has to be done a different way

Comment: @Amja, you might consider editing your question and put more details. For me, the question is ambiguous. Please check the **edit** in the answer.